# Hide Html inside of a <td> not the <td> itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This has to be a crazy basic question, but for the life of me I can't figure it out right now...

I have a `<td class="hide">Some text</td>`

I want only the TEXT/HTML **inside** of the `<td>` to be hidden, **NOT** the entire `<td>` itself. How can this be achieved with CSS??

**[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Rw2fL/)**

*Note

Applying a span inside it, etc isn't necessarily an option.

Comment: You can't do that if you don't want to wrap the text inside the `td` in a container...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of

```
display: none;
```

You could try

```
text-indent: -9999px;
```

Comment: Given the circumstance where OP cannot wrap the contents of the table cell in another tag, this is a pretty clever solution

Comment: You could also add `min-width: Xpx` to prevent the `td` cell from collapsing.

Comment: WOW, simply genius... I use that for Image replacement, never considered it for this. Thanks so much, works perfectly!!

Comment: Brilliant CSS! Why didn't I think of this!

Answer (score 2):

What about just making it transparent?

```
opacity: 0.0;
```

Comment: I was thinking of using `color: transparent`, which means that `td` cell would retain the original width.

Comment: Add in `display:table-cell;` and boom, works like a charm as well!

Answer (score 1):

You can either do:

```
$('.hide').css('color','rgba(0,0,0,0)');//will make the text transparent and retain the width
```

or

```
$('.hide').text('');//will delete the text, not retaining the width
```

or:

```
$('.hide').wrap('<span style="opacity:0">');//will use a span and retain the width
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8gs7k/1/)

Hope this helps!